# Writing a vector class c++

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

So I'm trying to write a vector class which can take objects without a default constructor. To do so I'm using an array of *raw* pointers. Thing is, when I'm instantiating a new vector, let's call it 2, based upon a previous vector, let's call it 1-- it points to the underlying address of said previous object, 1. So when I insert a new value into 1, 2 is updated as well.

```
#ifndef MYVECTOR_MYVECTOR_H
#define MYVECTOR_MYVECTOR_H

#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

template<typename T>
class MyVector;

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyVector<T>& myVec){
  out << "{";
  for(int i = 0; i < myVec.numElem; i++){
    out << &myVec.elements[i] << " ";
  }
  out << "}";
  return out;
}


template<typename T>
class MyVector{
  public:
      int numElem;
      int capacity;
      T** elements;

      MyVector(const unsigned int& numElements, const T& value) : numElem(numElements), capacity(numElements * 2){
          elements = new T*[capacity];
          for(int i = 0; i < numElem; i++){
              elements[i] = new T(value);
          }
      }

      template<typename U>
      MyVector(const std::vector<U>& values): numElem(values.size()), capacity(values.size() * 2){
        elements = new T*[capacity];
        for(int i = 0; i < numElem; i++){
            elements[i] = new T(values[i]);
        }
      }

    void insert(const unsigned& pos, const T& value){
        elements[numElem] = new T(*elements[numElem - 1]);
        numElem++;

        for(unsigned int i = numElem - 1; i > pos; i--){
            elements[i] = elements[i - 1];
        }
        elements[pos] = new T(value);
    }
};

#endif
```

Per comment #1:

```
class NoDefault {
 public:
  NoDefault(const int& value) : value(value) {}

  int value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const NoDefault& noDefault) {
  out << noDefault.value;
  return out;
}

int main() {
  MyVector<NoDefault> noDefaultVec(std::vector<NoDefault>{7,8,9,10,11});
  MyVector<MyVector<NoDefault>> vecvec(2, noDefaultVec);

  std::cout << "noDefaultVec = " << noDefaultVec << std::endl;
  std::cout << "vecvec = " << vecvec << std::endl;

  noDefaultVec.insert(3, 99);
  vecvec.insert(1, noDefaultVec);

  std::cout << "noDefaultVec = " << noDefaultVec << std::endl;
  std::cout << "vecvec = " << vecvec << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: " when I'm instantiating a new vector, let's call it 2, based upon a previous vector, let's call it 1" - how are you doing this? `MyVector letsCallIt2(letsCallIt1)` ? In that case you need to provide a copy constructor to make a deep copy. (By the way, you will also want to write a destructor to clean up your ` T**` ).

Comment: just in case you do this because `std::vector` cannot hold elements that have no default constructor: `std::vector` can hold elements that have no default constructor, you just cant call any method that would require to default construct an element

Comment: "To do so I'm using an array of raw pointers." This would vehave very differently from the standard vector, and thus deserve a completely new name.

Answer (score 1):

You perform a shallow copy instead of a deep copy.

A shallow copy of your vector creates a new collection which shares elements with an old one. What follows, any change made to the original object will cause a change in a new one. What you need in that case is a deep copy, which duplicates every element from the source to the destination. After performing such a copy you are left with two vectors with seperate set of data.

Providing a copy constructor for your class solves the problem, but you should also remember about implementing destructor and assignment operator, basing on [The Rule Of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You can also consider adding move constructor and move assignment operator (or one assignment operator following [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/6365556)).